# How to add fadeIn and fadeOut to idTabs plugin's JS snippet?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using the jQuery plugin idTabs [ [www.sunsean.com/idTabs][1] ] and it allows me to line tabs and tabs' content via element#id and element href="#id"

Ok, so I use this snippet:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#requestPool").idTabs();
 $(".tabs").idTabs();
 $(".miniTabs").idTabs(".active"); 
 $(".switchers").idTabs(".activePanel");
});
</script>
```

To run the plugin on two different areas: `div#requestPool` this has it's own tabs and it's own tab content, Also the `div.tabs` which is another place and has it's own tabs and it's own tabs content.

The `div.miniTabs` and div.switchers are the divs that includes the tabs links (tabs headers) and I putted them in the snippet to change the default selected tab class from `.selected` to `.active` and `.activePanel`

Now, what I would love to add is a nice fadeIn and fadeOut effects to the content of my tabs while browsing through them.

Thanks

Here is the HTML code for one of the tabbed areas:

```
<div id="requestPool">
 <!-- The tabs heads -->
 <div class="miniTabs">
  <a href="#today" class="active">Today</a> <!-- First active tab -->
  <a href="#tomorrow">Tomorrow</a>
  <a href="#friday">Friday</a>
  <a href="#saturday">Saturday</a>
  <a href="#sunday">Sunday</a>
  <a href="#monday">Monday</a>
  <a href="#tuesday">Tuesday</a>                                  
 </div>

 <!-- The tabs contents (the ones that I want them to fade in and out while browsing through them using the tabs above) -->
 <div id="today"class="miniTab"></div>
 <div id="tomorrow"class="miniTab"></div>
 <div id="friday"class="miniTab"></div>
 <div id="saturday"class="miniTab"></div>
 <div id="sunday"class="miniTab"></div>
 ...etc the week days
</div>
```

Thanks very much (again the tabs are working very fine, but without the fade effect which I want to have).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've checked the page you've mentioned, there's a solution there in Advanced section -> Animation. I've modified it a bit and tested, it seems fine:

In `<head>`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $(".miniTabs").idTabs(function(id,list,set){ 
        $("a",set).removeClass("active").filter("a[href='"+id+"']").addClass("active"); 
        for(i in list)$(list[i]).hide();
        $(id).fadeIn(); 
        return false; 
    }); 
});
</script>
```

In `<body>`:

```
<div id="requestPool">
 <div class="miniTabs">
  <a href="#today" class="active">Today</a>
  <a href="#tomorrow">Tomorrow</a>
  <a href="#friday">Friday</a>
  <a href="#saturday">Saturday</a>
  <a href="#sunday">Sunday</a>
 </div>
 <div id="today"class="miniTab">Today</div>
 <div id="tomorrow"class="miniTab">Tomorrow</div>
 <div id="friday"class="miniTab">Friday</div>
 <div id="saturday"class="miniTab">Saturday</div>
 <div id="sunday"class="miniTab">Sunday</div>
</div>
```

Cheers

G.